# How to determine on which index of an array is mouseover event occuring?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Basically, I have an array displayed and I want to show the index of the element on which I move my mouse over (`using onmouseover`) in a separate div (common for all the elements).

I want to implement a `submenu` thing where, if I move my mouse over another element in the `autosuggestion` array, the contents of the div change according to the index of that element.

I have tried to do this `using :hover (CSS)`, for which I have to place the show-on-hover class in the *`ngFor`. But, it makes a separate div for every element. The element is not common.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="autoSuggestContainer">
    <div *ngIf="autoSuggestOptions.length > 0" class="autosuggest-box">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let option of autoSuggestOptions let i=index">
          <a class="autosuggest-link" target="_blank" href="{{ option['url'] }}">
            <div class="autosuggest-item">
              <img class="result-type-icon" src="{{ getIconPath(getResultType(option)) }}">
              <p class="result-label">{{ option['term'] }}</p>

              <div class="only-show-on-hover" style="width:206px; height: 100%; float: right" display="inline-block">
                <p>{{i}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </ng-container>


    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.only-show-on-hover{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.autosuggest-item:hover .only-show-on-hover{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The index is showing in the above code also, but I want a separate div common for all the elements of the array.

Comment: So you want the single div with index outside of ngFor?

Comment: Yes, that div's contents will change when I hover over a different element, but displaying index is a start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the index, you need, inside your component, to store the state and change that state on mouse hover events:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option of autoSuggestOptions let i=index">
   <div class="autosuggest-item"
      (mouseenter)="state = i" (mouseleave)="state = null">
     ...
   </div>
</ng-container>
<div class="only-show-on-hover" *ngIf="state !== null">
   <p>{{state}}</p>
</div>
```

instead of `state = i` you can have proper function that will update your state.

Comment: @user9905924 don't forget to accept the answer if it solved you issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try something like this....

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list;let i=index">
 <div [title]="i" (mouseover)="showIdx(i)" (mouseleave)="hover.idx=-1"> 
   {{item.name}}</div>
</div>
<pre>hover.idx {{hover.idx}}</pre>
<div *ngIf="hover.idx === 1">
 item 1 selected
</div>
<div *ngIf="hover.idx === 2">
 item 2 selected
</div>
<div *ngIf="hover.idx === 3">
 item 3 selected
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
hover:any;
list:any[]=[
{name:'item a',type:'1'},
{name:'item b',type:'2'},
{name:'item c',type:'3'},
{name:'item d',type:'4'}
];
constructor(){
  this.hover={
    idx:0
  }

 showIdx(idx:number){
  this.hover.idx=idx;
 }
}
```

Hope this what you meant

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

Lets think of the popup thing as a modal, and take it outside of the loop. Each time a hover occurs send a ref of the hovered el and the modal el to the callback.

```
<div class="autoSuggestContainer" style="display: flex">
<div *ngIf="1 > 0" class="autosuggest-box">

    <ng-container *ngFor="let option of ['sug0', 'sug1', 'sug2']; let i=index" >
        <a class="autosuggest-link" target="_blank">
          <div #sugg (mouseenter)="onHover($event, sugg, modal)" (mouseleave)="onLeave(modal)" class="autosuggest-item">
            <img class="result-type-icon">
      <p class="result-label">option</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</ng-container>

<div #modal class="only-show-on-hover" display="inline-block">
  <p>modal</p>
</div>

</div>
```

TS:

Then get client rect of the hovered el so you know where to position the modal. Finally use style to set the modal around the hover el wherever suits your need. On leave hide the modal.

```
onHover(ev, sugg, modal) {

  modal.style.display = 'block';

  const rectSugg = sugg.getBoundingClientRect();

  modal.style.top = `${rectSugg.y}px`;
  modal.style.left = `${rectSugg.width}px`;

}

onLeave(modal) {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

CSS:

Hide the modal for the first render.

```
.only-show-on-hover {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 206px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Here is a few additional tips about animating and hiding modals. 
 [Animating Modal Views](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animating-modal-views)